# Classifying operator's spectrum

Tags: operator-theory, mathematical-physics

I am working in the space of $l^2 (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...)$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty |\alpha_j|^2<\infty$.
I need to classify the spectrum of the folloowing operator $$L|v> = (\alpha_2,\alpha_3,...)$$
where $|v> = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...)$.

I have realised that $||L||=1$ so the spectrum must be in $|z|\leq 1, z\in \mathbb{C}$, since $L$ is a linear bounded operator. Now, as far as I know, I should check whether $(L - \lambda I)^{-1}$ exists and if it is bounded or not but I do not know how to approach this.

Comment: You want to know if given $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)\in\ell^2$ whether there is $(b_1,b_2,\ldots)\in\ell^2$ with $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)=(b_2-\lambda b_1,b_3-\lambda b_2,\ldots)$. I'd get solving!

Answer (score 1):

If $|\lambda|<1$ then the vector
$$
  v=(1,\lambda,\lambda^2, \lambda^3, ...)
  $$
lies in your space and
$$L(v)=\lambda v.$$
So $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and hence the open disk is contained in the point spectrum.  Moreover, you already know that the spectrum of $L$ is contained in the closed disk, so it is now enough to analyze complex numbers $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|=1$.  Could these be eigenvalues?